# Magento, add Css file from media folder

Tags: css, magento, media

Is it possible tu add a Css file from the "media" folder!? 
In the normal way we put the css file into the "skin" folder and then we use "addCss()"!
But I need it to be in the "media" folder !
Thanks for Helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$path = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'my_folder/';
$file=$this->getTypeCss();
$param='rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"';
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addItem('link_rel', $path.$file, $param);

return parent::_prepareLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can this not just be done by using the `<link>` tag in head.phtml?